# Changing order of shopping cart totals in Magento transactional emails and user account

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am having a requirement that I have to change the order of totals in a transactional emails and user account in Magento.

My requirement is shipping charge should display after Tax.

Currently it is displaying as Subtotal-Shipping charge-Tax-Grand Total and I need as Subtotal-Tax-Shipping charge-Grand total. Can anyone help me from where I can edit this.

I Am using Magento ver. 1.7.0.2

And the same thing in admin panel order details.

Please answer me ASAP... It will be very helpfull for me . I have stuck in this from 2 days

Answer (score 1):

Did you take a look at 
[image]

> Admin -> System -> Config -> Sales -> Checkout Totals Sort Order

Comment: It will work only for checkout page not email and user account